# Printing in ios: if the printer is connected to the mac, could it print from the simulator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, printing

I'm reading [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html) to add the printing functionality.

The Printer-options sheet is displayed, but when I try to select my printer, the message "printer not found" appears.

The printer is connected via usb to the imac.

Can the print functionality be tested from the simulator?

**EDIT**

I tried with a wireless printer (installing also the airprint activator on the mac). Now I can see the printer from the simulator.

I don't know if I should be able to really print from the simulator and/or see some printer msg in the printer simulator.

**EDIT**

I resolved using the Printer Simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible to print from the simulator on both real and simulated printer. However, I succeeded to print from the device by using the Printer Simulator and by activating airprint on the mac with AirPrint Activator.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is a AirPrint feature. iDevice will only detect printers which are has AirPrint. There are about 12-14 hp printers currently supported. If you are looking for any printer, this is not possible. While developing we can use printer simulator or buy the supported AirPrint printer.

Comment: In fact, also if the printer doesn't support AirPrint, it's possible to print by activating AirPrint (e.g. with AirPrintActivator) on the pc/mac connected to the printer. Obviously, in this case, the pc/mac  has to be switched on. For a real wireless printing, as you said, it needs a suited hp printer.